# What can I destroy with my arrows?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I want to build an archery range in Minecraft.  I want to have targets pop up in different places like an FPS tutorial.  I need some way to detect whether the arrows hit the targets or not.

What can I change by the impact of an arrow?

Comment: If an arrow lands on a minecart track, it will stop a minecart. This probably isn't too useful in this situation though...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The extent to which arrows can affect Redstone circuits is covered [on the wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Bow#Arrows_and_Circuits).

Arrows can trigger **wooden** pressure plates and buttons, however these cannot be moved with pistons (although you could reveal them).

For your range, I'd suggest making it out of **boats** and **paintings**. These will break when arrows hit them and turn into items, which can then fall and trigger pressure plates.

Answer (score 6):

I use a minecart on top of a detector rail. Easy to reset, and can be shot from a distance without much problem.

Comment: When this question was asked, minecarts took several arrows to destroy.  Now that they only take one, this is a good deal more plausible.

Comment: This method has been used in FVDisco's archery range, so, it does work.